# Fitting input data into Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, probability, gaussian, normal-distribution, data-fitting

I'm currently reading papers on Variational Autoencoders (VAE). According to this article (http://proceedings.mlr.press/v95/guo18a/guo18a.pdf):

> By fitting the input data sample x(i) into the Gaussian distribution with the reconstructed mean vector and the reconstructed standard deviation vector, we can get the corresponding reconstruction probability N (x(i)|µxˆ(i, l), σxˆ(i, l)) of the lth generated latent vector.

Basically, I don't understand what "fitting the input data sample x(i) into the Gaussian distribution" means.
I assume we first build a Multivariate Gaussian distribution with the vectors µxˆ(i, l) and σxˆ(i, l). But then, what does that mean to fit a vector into that distribution?

Also, does the result of that calculation correspond to what we call the likelihood then?

Many thanks,

Guillaume

Comment: Maybe [Data Science Stack](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate to find answer, even if the audience is very lower. Just saying in case you don't find help here.